# How to display colours of Material 3 in a meaningful way?

Tags: flutter, material-ui, material-design

The theme builds itself with `colorSchemeSeed`, but I have no idea which colors go for which widgets and properties as they are all named confusingly.

There is no such proper website service yet to display a `colorSchemeSeed` with a meaningful understandable layout. So how can I get the colors currently that I need in a quick fashion? For instance I need the color generated for the `subtitle` in a `Card` widget in Material 3, how do I get the name of it to use in `Theme.of(context)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I recommend using Figma and the Material Theme Builder plugin. Figma is a Desktop application which allows all sorts of editing, and with it there are plugins; one of them is the Material Theme Builder by Google which allows you to pick a color and it generates the colours for you, displaying them.

To get any of the colorSchemeSeed colors, simply use this code:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.findColorHere
```

Your IDE will autocomplete findColorHere to all the color variables like primaryContainer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here:
https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/#/custom
try different colors and download file.